# IF EXISTS SQL Statement won't work

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-express

I'm getting this error from the below T-SQL query.

**Error message:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near '101'

Can anyone spot where the error here is? Using Management Studio / SQLServerExpress The desired result is a new record inserted or an existing one update.

**Below is my query:**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID = 101) 
UPDATE Product SET  
ProductID = 101 , InsurerID = 1, CategoryID =1, Name = 'Landlord',
[description] ='Allianz Landlord', label = 'NULL', AssumptionRef  ='NULL',
QuoteProviderKey ='A75',AccidentalDamageCover =0, ProductBenefitGroupID = 11,
IsAvailableToBuy =1,IsAvalableToDisplay =0,PercentageContentsCover ='NULL', 
ProductPolicyView ='NULL', ProductFee =NULL 
WHERE ProductID = 101 
ELSE 
INSERT INTO Product 
VALUES 101,1,1,'Landlord','Allianz Landlord','NULL','NULL','A75',0,11,1,0,'NULL','NULL',NULL
WHERE ProductID  = 101
```

Comment: have you tested the component parts of the call separately?

Comment: you have a `WHERE ProductID  = 101` at the end of the `INSERT` statement. Also add () around `VALUES` like this  `VALUES(101,....... )`

Comment: Add parentheses to VALUES (...)

Comment: simple typo, should be closed

Comment: You do not mention which version of SQL Server you are using but for SQL Server 2008 and up you should consider using `MERGE` instead of `IF EXISTS`. The latter can fail in environments with high concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement has a `WHERE` clause with `VALUES` set, which isn't valid:

```
INSERT INTO Product
VALUES 101
    ,1
    ,1
    ,'Landlord'
    ,'Allianz Landlord'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'A75'
    ,0
    ,11
    ,1
    ,0
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,NULL
WHERE ProductID = 101
```

You are also missing `()` around the `VALUES` section, as well as the columns listed out (though, that won't give an error, but you should get in the habit of explicitly listing the columns)

Your statement should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Product
(
    ProductID
    ,InsurerID
    ,CategoryID
    ,NAME
    ,[description]
    ,label 
    ,AssumptionRef 
    ,QuoteProviderKey 
    ,AccidentalDamageCover 
    ,ProductBenefitGroupID 
    ,IsAvailableToBuy 
    ,IsAvalableToDisplay 
    ,PercentageContentsCover 
    ,ProductPolicyView 
    ,ProductFee 
)
VALUES 
(
    101
    ,1
    ,1
    ,'Landlord'
    ,'Allianz Landlord'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,'A75'
    ,0
    ,11
    ,1
    ,0
    ,'NULL'
    ,'NULL'
    ,NULL
)
```

Another thing to question is why you're using string `'NULL'` values.  If you're intending these fields to be `NULL`, they should be `NULL` and not `'NULL'`

Comment: Thanks my friend, appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last where clause because according to your scenario you dont need where in INSERT statement 
try running this one

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Product WHERE ProductID = 101)  UPDATE Product SET   ProductID = 101 , InsurerID = 1, CategoryID =1, Name = 'Landlord', [description] ='Allianz Landlord', label = 'NULL', AssumptionRef  ='NULL', QuoteProviderKey ='A75',AccidentalDamageCover
=0, ProductBenefitGroupID = 11, IsAvailableToBuy =1,IsAvalableToDisplay =0,PercentageContentsCover ='NULL',  ProductPolicyView ='NULL', ProductFee =NULL  WHERE ProductID = 101  ELSE  INSERT INTO Product  VALUES 101,1,1,'Landlord','Allianz Landlord','NULL','NULL','A75',0,11,1,0,'NULL','NULL',NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the begin end

```
IF (.....)
BEGIN

END
ELSE
BEGIN

END
```

Comment: you can skip `BEGIN` ... `END` if there is only 1 statement in the block. the error is caused by a different error.